# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':rctmgl']

Tags: android, react-native, expo, build.gradle

I'm working on Expo and recently updated the Expo SDK Version to 45.0 and just encountered this problem when running the `eas build -p android`

Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':rctmgl'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Here is my gradle.build

[image: 1]

Here is the build error

[image: 2]

Please help with this build error.